# .NET Control.ID property inconsistency

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please have a look at the code below:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim c1 As New CheckBox
        c1.ID = "Test1/" 'line 7
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(c1)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each c As Control In Page.Controls
            For Each d As Control In c.Controls
                For Each f As Control In d.Controls
                    For Each g As Control In f.Controls
                        For Each h As Control In g.Controls
                            If TypeOf h Is CheckBox Then
                                Dim cbox As New CheckBox
                                cbox = CType(h, CheckBox)
                                MsgBox(cbox.Checked) 'Line 20
                            End If
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

There is a placeholder on the default.aspx page called: PlaceHolder1.  The MessageBox on line 20 is printing True.  Please have a look at the quote below taken from the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx

> "Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore
>   character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces
>   or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error."

/ is not an alphanumeric character, so how can the message box print true?  If you change line 7 to: `c1.ID = "Test1:"`, then this prints false as I would expect (because : (colon) is a none alphanumeric).  There isn't consistency.  I am missing something.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need a control with a backslash in the Id?

Comment: @Blachshma, I am asking why .NET allows you to enter certain characters into the ID field even though they are not alphanumerics?

Comment: It's an interesting find. But you didn't need all the nested loops. Can't you just access the CheckBox from Page_Load and still demonstrate the behavior?

Comment: BTW, I create `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox`es at runtime all the time and set the `Name` to various strings which would not be acceptable at design time (non-alphanumeric, spaces). I'm just happy it works and don't ask these questions :)

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to establish what characters are not allowed at runtime.

Comment: You could loop through all ascii characters and see which work and which don't. Add the "false" ones to a list of non-working characters.

Comment: Yes, I may do that. Do you know the reason for the inconsistency?

Comment: No I don't know the reason.

Comment: @DanVerdolino - The OP is not using System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox controls.  It is the web version.